# Visual Studio Code executes file only from Ctrl+F5

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Can anyone explain why Visual Studio Code don't execute some files from [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmEQZ.png)? Only Ctrl+5 works. When i am runnug code from button it gaves me  ["invalid syntax"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkCui.png)?

Comment: what is the default  version of your python?

Comment: It's 3.9.0 https://i.imgur.com/0zMHT8k.png

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you are trying the key when you are currently have an interpreter open in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:** This is because the current VSCode terminal is a Python interactive window, it will execute correctly when you enter a python statement, but the command to click the run button is similar to"`D:/Users/.../AppData/Local/ Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/.../test09/a.py`", it is not a python statement, so the console returns "`SyntaxError`".

The reason you can use "`Ctrl+F5`" or "`F5`" to execute code is that this is a debugging process and it will run in the "Python Debug console" terminal.

**Solution:** Enter the statement "`exit()`" in the console to exit the Python interactive window.

[image]